# Expo Error - Android sqlite no such table

Tags: android, sqlite, expo

I am coding an app in Expo using sqlite database. On iOS, everything is OK, but on Android it's not working.

LOG  Error  [Error: Error code : no such table: cars]

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen';
import AddCarScreen from './Screens/AddCarScreen';
import CarDetailScreen from './Screens/CarDetailScreen';
import EditCarScreen from './Screens/EditCarScreen.js';

// Funkce pro inicializaci databáze
        const initializeDatabase = () => {
          const db = SQLite.openDatabase('MyCars.db');

          db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(
              `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cars (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                brand TEXT,
                model TEXT,
                licensePlate TEXT,
                vin TEXT,
                technicalInspectionDate TEXT,
                serviceInspectionDate TEXT,
                highwayStampValidityDate TEXT,
                techInspNotif1 TEXT,
                techInspNotif2 TEXT,
                servInspNotif1 TEXT,
                servInspNotif2 TEXT,
                highwayStampNotif1 TEXT,
                highwayStampNotif2 TEXT
              );`,
              [],
              () => console.log('Table cars created successfully'),
              (error) => console.log('Error creating table: ' + error.message)
            );
          });
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    initializeDatabase();
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
  }, []);

  // Funkce pro požádání o zapnutí notifikací
  async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
    const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      alert('Omlouváme se, nemáme povolení zasílat vám push notifikace.');
      return;
    }
    // Pokud chcete získat a využít token, doplňte kód zde
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'>
        <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name='AddCar' component={AddCarScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name='CarDetail' component={CarDetailScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name='EditCar' component={EditCarScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I tried using the emulator in Android Studio, the Expo Go app, and I even installed apk on physical device.